# Is there any evidence that vegan and/or rawfood diets are beneficial to people that suffer from rheumatoid arthritis?

Tags: therapeutic-diet, rawfood-diet

Symptoms of **rheumatoid arthritis** often get worse on diets abundant in meats, especially red meats.

Can vegan and/or raw food diets have positive effects on people with this disease?

Comment: raw food and veganism are two totally different things.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Arthritis Research UK](http://www.arthritisresearchuk.org/arthritis-information/arthritis-and-daily-life/diet-and-arthritis/do-vegetarian-or-vegan-diets-help.aspx), there is **some evidence of vegan diet improving medical condition of people suffering from arthritis**.

This may be part of due to **lack of red meat** in such diet, which has been found to be linked to increased risk of this illness. Another [culprit](http://www.pcrm.org/health/health-topics/foods-and-arthritis) that lacks in vegan/raw diets which is mentioned with regard to arthritis is **dairy**.

It might be important for vegan people suffering form arthritis to see whether they have **sufficient protein intake** as this can lack in vegan diet and is mentioned to be important in tackling the symptoms. Other important parts of the diet that helps with arthritis are eg. **Omega 3, vitamin C** and **vitamin E**.

Answer (score 4):

Results seem to be mixed, some studies show a positive effect, others no effect at all. The studies referenced by [Arthritis Research](http://www.arthritis.org/living-with-arthritis/arthritis-diet/anti-inflammatory/vegan-and-vegetarian-diets.php) suggest that going vegan seems to show better results than being vegetarian. Going vegetarian or vegan may have the additional benefit that you're more likely to [lose weight](http://www.eatthis.com/veganism-found-to-be-the-best-diet-for-weight-loss) over time which will put less strain on your joints. Most studies don't really run long enough to prove this though.

On the other hand, I suppose it's only fair to point out if you are thinking of becoming vegetarian and vegan solely for the above reasons that there is also evidence that the [consumption of oily fish](http://www.arthritisresearchuk.org/arthritis-information/complementary-and-alternative-medicines/cam-report/complementary-medicines-for-rheumatoid-arthritis/fish-oils.aspx) can improve the symptoms of rheumatoid arthritis.

According to [arthritisresearchuk.org](http://www.arthritisresearchuk.org/arthritis-information/arthritis-and-daily-life/diet-and-arthritis/how-can-changing-my-diet-help-my-arthritis.aspx), "On balance, changing your diet probably won’t have as great an impact on your arthritis as the medicine prescribed by your doctor will."

Comment: Or just fish oil or flaxeed oil tablets?

Answer (score 0):

Many [studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11177171) shows that arthritis get worse be meat, the reason behind this is [Omega-6 fatty acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-6_fatty_acid) which increases the inflamation in joints, A 2011 study from the University of South Florida reported that eating food rich in vitamin C prevent the chances of rheumatoid arthritis. My friend was suffered from rheumatoid arthritis and doctor prescribed to eat strawberries, kiwi, pineapple, or cantaloupe.